# Can frozen raw meat be defrosted and frozen again

Tags: turkey

A frozen joint of turkey was partly defrosted cut into 2 and the other half was re-frozen

Surely this is not safe

Answer (score 6):

It's perfectly safe if the turkey wasn't kept in the danger zone for longer than the maximum recommended time.

If it was kept appropriately cold for the minimal amount of time possible, there's nothing "unsafe" about refreezing anything.

What you *do* lose with refreezing is quality. Freezing is a damaging process for many products, meat included. The reason you're warned to not defrost and refreeze is generally for *quality* reasons, not for food safety reasons.